Bluetooth audio channels per app per device
Major part of my issue is wording the title and search query - I've searched here and on the web and could not find info.
I found that I can change the setting of Bluetooth (audio) devices to handle calls and/or audio.  Furthermore, I can select "Audio device type" to be either Headphones, Speaker or Other (as per Android's Settings app).
I want to know if it is possible to have it more granular, i.e. only have the audio of an app play through audio device and have, say, notifications play through the phone's speaker.  Thus music will not be interrupted or volume suppressed when playing a notification alert. I don't want to mute notification when using Bluetooth audio devices.
If it is possible - is there another setting or app to do this?

Android version: 14
One UI version: 6.1
Phone: Galaxy A55 5G


Wonder if there is an API that one can write an app for this?

I've found something related. Not 100% what I was looking for but here it is:
Settings->Sounds and vibration->Separate app sound

I can't quote a reference for it.  It is a fairly common question with no answers.  And I have not found a solution either.  It would appear that there is no such setting.

Thank you for your response. I'd hope there was something
